# Using XPATH fn:concat in MySQL ExtractValue does not process more than two arguments

Tags: mysql, xml, xslt, xpath

When using the XSLT fn:concat() function within the XPATH of a MySQL ExtractValue function, a string with only the first two arguments are returned.

For example:

```
SELECT ExtractValue("<xml><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></xml>", 'concat(/xml/a,/xml/b,/xml/c)')
```

This should return "123", but instead returns "12".

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

<sub>I realize that the following workaround can be used:
`concat(concat(/xml/a,/xml/b,/xml/c),/xml/c)`
But seriously?</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT ExtractValue("<xml><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></xml>", '//a | //b | //c')
```

or (more likely) this:

```
SELECT 
  ExtractValue("<xml><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></xml>", '//a') AS a,
  ExtractValue("<xml><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></xml>", '//b') AS b,
  ExtractValue("<xml><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></xml>", '//c') AS c
```

Note that the xpath function `concat` which you have tried will return the concatenation of strings like:

```
example: concat('foo', 'bar')
result : 'foo bar'
```

Comment: My question was in regards to why the XPATH function is not returning the proper result, not how to accomplish the concatenation (I provided an alternate way, and one could also use MySQL's CONCAT function).

Comment: it is returning the proper result. you may expect something that the function not pretends to be. This was what I tried to show you. You'll have to read the manual carefully

Comment: Nope. Just tried:
SELECT ExtractValue("<xml />", 'concat("hello", "world", "!")');
Result: "helloworld" (no exclamation point)
Running MySQL 5.5.31

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately the mysql version of the xpath/concat function supports only two arguments. Have updated the example. I know it is unsatisfying but you would have to use this: `SELECT ExtractValue("<xml />", "concat('hello', concat(' ', concat('world', '!')))")` .. Why do you have downvoted me, Aaron? It looks like I'm the only person who was willing to help you

Comment: btw, have you ever had a look into this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html ?

Comment: My question was whether the XPATH concat() function is not working as it should (according to WC3 standards) or whether I was doing something wrong. I clearly stated that there are other ways to *accomplish* this (e.g. nested contact() functions, using MySQL's CONCAT() in certain scenarios, or your example) - that was not my question. Yes, I saw the documentation - what does that have to do with anything?